# How to export images with vector graphics for web in Adobe XD?

Tags: vector, export, adobe-xd

I'm working on a webpage where we are using photos that have vector graphic elements. I've tried exporting these as svg's, and I'm running into an issue where some of the photo elements are not being saved into the svg.

Is there any way in Adobe XD to export where both photos and vectors are present?

Comment: What software are you using? Are the vector elements not rasterized? What export settings are you using? Some more info is needed to diagnose the problem.

Comment: read this: https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/xd/help/export-design-assets.html#export-svg

Answer (score 1):

If your image has mixed media, photos and vectors, than export it  as .jpg or .png at a size that's best balance between efficiency and quality.